# Remover header http em socket C

Tags: c, socket, http-headers

Fiz um socket em C. Este programa é operado por linha de comando e compilado sobre Linux. Ele recebe como parâmetro uma URI completa e um nome de arquivo, e em seguida conecta ao servidor, recupera a página e salva no arquivo informado. 
Após obter os dados remotos. O arquivo recebido pela função **recv** vem com um HEADER.
A questão é: Como remover esse **HEADER** antes do arquivo ser gravado pela função fwrite().

Answer (score 1):

Nao comeces a escrever o ficheiro final antes do header terminar

```
int headerterminado = 0;
char *p = NULL;
while (recv(socket, buffer, ...)) {
    p = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
    if (p) headerterminado = 1;
}
```

'E claro que tens que ter atencao ao caso que o `"\r\n\r\n"` 'e partido em 2 `recv()`s.

Comment: Não funcionou, estou tentando fazer isso com com uma maquina de estado,  byte a byte.  Desculpe a ignorância, mas nas estou conseguindo postar o meu código formatado aqui neste post.

Comment: cria os estados `HEADER0`, `HEADER1`, `HEADER2`, e `HEADER3`. Quando estás em `HEADER0` e recebes um `'\r'` passa a estado `HEADER1`; senão permanece em estadio `HEADER0`; se estás em estado `HEADER1` e recebes `'\n'` passa a `HEADER2`; senão volta a `HEADER0`; quando estado for `HEADER2` e recebes `'\r'` passa a `HEADER3`; quando estado for `HEADER3` e recebes `'\n'` esse `'\n'` é o último byte do header.